# Slowing performance of UIcollectionview

Tags: objective-c, performance, ios7, uicollectionview

Befor that collection view performance was very good, but when i added the rounded corner and border then its slowing the performance.

```
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)clView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
```

=============================

```
    cell.layer.borderWidth = 1;
    cell.layer.borderColor = [[UIColor lightGrayColor] colorWithAlphaComponent:0.5].CGColor;

    cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor app_cell_background_color];
    [cell.layer setCornerRadius:5.0f];

    cell.layer.shouldRasterize = YES;
    cell.layer.rasterizationScale = [UIScreen mainScreen].scale;
```

=====================
}

Can anyone suggest how i will able to get same performance as before.

I searched and got to use image for border but any other method using which i will be able to get the same performance using layer.

Comment: radius, borders and transparency, all hit performance very heavily.. mainly on iPhone 4 and older devices. Have you tried turning off those last 2 lines of rasterization? depending on what you're doing, they not always help with performance

Comment: I added the code you posted to a project I had, and didn't see any performance hit when the code was placed in the custom cell's init method. You might try putting it there, and see if that makes a difference.